# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using multiple model a single razor page but i getting error when i retrieving data according by specified id.Error (The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Proj.Model.PersonInfo', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Proj.Model.Person'.)

```
public class PersonInfo
{
    public int PersonId{get;set;}
    public string Firstname{get;set;}
    public string Lastname{get;set;}
}

public class ContactInfo
{
    public int PersonId{get;set;}
    public string Address{get;set;}
    public string Telephone{get;set;}
}

public class Person
{
    public PersonInfo PersonInfo{get;set;}
    public ContactInfo ContactInfo{get;set;}
}

public ActionResult PersonInfo(int id)
{
    return View(db.GetPersonInfo().FirstOrDefault(m => m.PersonId == id));
}

public List<PersonInfo> GetPersonInfo()
{
    List<PersonInfo> info = null;
    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(_conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM PERSON_INFO";
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                info = new List<PersonInfo>();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    info.Add(new PersonInfo
                    {
                        PersonId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["P_ID"]),
                        Firstname = reader["FIRST_NAME"],
                        Lastname = reader["LAST_NAME"].ToString()
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return info;
}
```

Comment: your question itself states answer, pass model to view which is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this from

```
public ActionResult PersonInfo(int id)
{
    return View(db.GetPersonInfo().FirstOrDefault(m => m.PersonId == id));
}
```

to

```
public ActionResult PersonInfo(int id)
{
    var model = new Person { PersonInfo = db.GetPersonInfo().FirstOrDefault(m => m.PersonId == id)} 
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Kane, Thank yo very much... You have solved my problem.